# improving performance of function call using ctypes

Tags: python, c++, performance, optimization, ctypes

I'm am trying to call a function written in C++ from a python code, the method that I'm using is ctypes. here is how I'm doing the wrapper:

```
def render(vertex, tri, texture, src_img):

    cRenderer = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary("renderer.so")

    cvertex = ((ctypes.c_double * len(vertex))(*vertex))
    nver = int(vertex.shape[0] / 3)

    ntri = tri.shape[0]
    tri = np.hstack(tri)
    ctri = ((ctypes.c_double * len(tri))(*tri))

    texture = np.hstack(texture)
    ctexture = ((ctypes.c_double * len(texture))(*texture))

    width = src_img.shape[0]
    height = src_img.shape[1]
    nChannels = src_img.shape[2]

    src_img = np.hstack(np.hstack(src_img))
    csrc_img = ((ctypes.c_double * len(src_img))(*src_img))

    cimg = ((ctypes.c_double * len(src_img))(*src_img))

    cRenderer.render(cvertex, ctri, ctexture, nver, ntri,
    csrc_img, width, height, nChannels, cimg)

    img = np.array(cimg).reshape(nChannels, height*width)

    return img.reshape(width, height, nChannels)
```

The C++ function takes an array of vertices, triangles, textures, a few numbers and input/output images.

I wrote the code in the most primitive way possible as this is the first time I use ctypes.
When I started doing some profiling I found that the function is spending most of the time on converting the arrays, for example:

```
cvertex = ((ctypes.c_double * len(vertex))(*vertex))
```

Is there a way to convert this to a passable argument in a more efficient way?
Are there any other methods other than ctypes and give better performance?

Any other advice to speed up this function is welcome :)

Comment: I believe `np.array.ctypes.data` returns a pointer to the raw array data that can be passed to ctypes.